# How to capture row id from table body click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you get the id from a row element that has been dynamically created. Below is the code that I have tried but it will not fire the event.

**HTML**

```
   <table id="tblRawMaterials" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                A
            </th>
            <th>
                B
            </th>
            <th>
                C
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr id="DCB4325E-951C-67E3-1E8F-7270D488A1EB"  >
        <td>G20002</td>
        <td>1,783</td>
        <td>2,000</td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
 $("#tblRawMaterials tbody").click( function(e) {
           // Here i need to capture row id of clicked cell.
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the equivalent (old) sintax of on, exactly the same concept:

```
$("#tblRawMaterials tbody").delegate('tr', 'click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

You need to use event delegation, in this way the event is attached to the parent tbody and fired anytime that a tr is clicked. It doesn't depend on the tr, so it will work also for elements dynamically added.

Please check che [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25cqeg4y/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use event delegation, in this way the event is attached to the parent `tbody` and fired anytime that a `tr` is clicked. It doesn't depend on the `tr`, so it will work also for elements dynamically added.

```
$("#tblRawMaterials tbody").on('tr','click',function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

use jQuery [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

> **Description**: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.

```
$("#tblRawMaterials tbody").delegate('tr','click',function(e) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Mahetha : i cant use this code tr is dynamically added /removed

Comment: this code will work with dynamically added /removed `tr`

Comment: @NishitMaheta you are welcome! I guess Rakin needed to know the reason

Comment: @Francescoes. yes you are rite.

Comment: @Francescoes. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function..using jquery-1.6.2

Comment: @Rakin answer you accept is not proper way to get `tr` id and it is very slow process . you can use `delegate` as explain in my answer which is fast then accepted answer.

Comment: @NishitMaheta `not proper way to get tr id and it is very slow process`
1. Why it is not proper way?
2. How can you say this is very slow process?
Please explain...

Comment: @NishitMaheta Actually your code doesn't work. You don't give to the delegate function the parameter in the proper order. 
@Jonh R you should not check for `closest` but of if the `NODENAME` is `TR`, this makes slower your code, but correct, the important point is the concept, no the code

Comment: If you are using a version of jQuery >= 1.7 you shouldn't be using delegate... stick with using .on

Comment: @Dan indeed the version is 1.6.2

Comment: @NishitMaheta Please check this line `.on('tr','click',` in your answer. In which parameter is not in proper order.

Comment: And I don't know for what reason my answer has been down voted.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this also with `closest`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tblRawMaterials tbody").click(function(e) {
    var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
      rowId = ($tr).attr("id"); // Here you can capture the row id of clicked cell.
    alert(rowId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblRawMaterials" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        A
      </th>
      <th>
        B
      </th>
      <th>
        C
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="DCB4325E-951C-67E3-1E8F-7270D488A1EB">
      <td>G20002</td>
      <td>1,783</td>
      <td>2,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE :**

If you really need `delegate`, then you can use the following code snippets.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate("#tblRawMaterials tbody", "click", function (e) {
        var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
          rowId = ($tr).attr("id"); // Here you can capture the row id of clicked cell.
        alert(rowId);
    });
});
```

**Note:** Here I didn't bind click event for `tr` element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: $(e.target).closest('tr'),  to $(e.target).closest('tr');

Comment: @Rakin while declaring many variables, we can use  single `var` keyword for all the variables with `,`

Comment: Down voter please explain the reason while down voting.

Comment: @Rakin Please check my **UPDATE**

Comment: @JohnR doesn't make any sense to attach the event in the whole document if it is only needed in a part of it, please have a look on mine

Comment: @Francescoes. Representing the `document` I have bond click event only for `"#tblRawMaterials tbody"` (`tbody`). Not for whole document. 
And please check the OP's questions first line `i cant use table row click event`. So only I have bond click event for `tbody` and hence I am suppose to use `closest`.

Comment: He says that.  because the `tr` can be added or removed dynamically, so the only way to make it work is the event delegation. About your solution, the event is bound in the whole document, but you do something only when is clicked the `#tblRawMaterials tbody`, but it checks anytime that you click everywhere

Comment: @Francescoes. Now only I got your point what you are trying to say. I agree with you.

Answer (score -4):

**try this**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#tblRawMaterials tr').click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });

});
```